# multy line string concatenation and writing to a text file

Tags: python

I am using the os library of python to help me do the following:

1. Ask the user for a path.
2. Print all the directories and files included in it.
3. Save the information in a text file.

this is my code:

```
import os
text = 'List:'
def print_tree(dir_path,text1):
    for name in os.listdir(dir_path):
        full_path = os.path.join(dir_path, name)        

        x = name.find('.')
        if x!= -1:
            print name #replace with full path if needed
            text1 = text1 + name
        else:
            print '------------------------------------'
            text1 = text1 + '------------------------------------' 
            print name
            text1 = text1 + name 

        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            os.path.split(name)
            print '------------------------------------'
            text1 = text1 + '------------------------------------'
            print_tree(full_path,text1)

path = raw_input('give me a dir path')
print_tree(path,text)
myfile = open('text.txt','w')
myfile.write(text)
```

I have two problems. First, although there's no error whatsoever, the only thing that actually exists in the text file after running this is 'List:'. Also i don't know how to use string concatenation in order to put each file name on a different line. What am i missing? How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Add "\n" to put text in new line.

Comment: @furas Say '\n List:'? Would that be correct?

Comment: No. "one line" + "\n" + "new line" + "\n" + "another line". or "one line\nnew line\nanother line"

Comment: @ppperry text1 is merely a parameter. I pass the actually variable called 'text' when i call the function. But as i stated above there are no errors. The program runs normally, displays the files but doesn't write them in the text.txt

Comment: You are appending to `text1`, but saving `text` to file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Python, and the `+=` operator on them is just an illusion. You can concatenate a string all you want in the function, but unless you return it, the string outside the function will not change: `text1 = text1 + 'blah'` creates a new string, and assigns its reference to `text1`. The string outside the function has not changed. The solution is to build up a string and then return it:

```
import os
text = 'List:' + os.linesep
def print_tree(dir_path,text1):
    for name in os.listdir(dir_path):
        full_path = os.path.join(dir_path, name)        

        x = name.find('.')
        if x!= -1:
            print name #replace with full path if needed
            text1 = text1 + name + os.linesep
        else:
            print '------------------------------------'
            text1 = text1 + '------------------------------------' + os.linesep
            print name
            text1 = text1 + name + os.linesep

        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            os.path.split(name)
            print '------------------------------------'
            text1 = text1 + '------------------------------------' + os.linesep
            text1 = print_tree(full_path,text1)
    return text1

path = raw_input('give me a dir path')
text = print_tree(path,text)
myfile = open('text.txt','w')
myfile.write(text)
```

I have also take the liberty of appending `os.linesep` to your concatenated strings. This is done by default by `print`, so if you want things to look the same, it is a good idea.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for you help. I can't believe i forgot to return :/

Comment: Glad it helped. Please select this answer in that case.